# Using WinDBG to Identify Defective Function in C# program written in VS2012

Tags: c#, exception, windbg

I get the following errors when using Windbg to debug a C# application written in VS2012 on another machine (it is running on the development machine, but not on a different test machine)

```
ModLoad: 00fd0000 01146000   ECM.exe
ModLoad: 77400000 7753c000   ntdll.dll
ModLoad: 6fca0000 6fcea000   C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\MSCOREE.DLL
ModLoad: 76240000 76314000   C:\Windows\system32\KERNEL32.dll
ModLoad: 756c0000 7570b000   C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
(470.fb8): Break instruction exception - code 80000003 (first chance)
eax=00000000 ebx=00000000 ecx=0015f588 edx=774470f4 esi=fffffffe edi=00000000
eip=774a05a6 esp=0015f5a4 ebp=0015f5d0 iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na pe nc
cs=001b  ss=0023  ds=0023  es=0023  fs=003b  gs=0000             efl=00000246
ntdll!LdrpDoDebuggerBreak+0x2c:
774a05a6 cc              int     3
```

After pressing g to continu I get

```
ModLoad: 759d0000 75a70000   C:\Windows\system32\ADVAPI32.dll
ModLoad: 760f0000 7619c000   C:\Windows\system32\msvcrt.dll
ModLoad: 775e0000 775f9000   C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\sechost.dll
ModLoad: 76540000 765e2000   C:\Windows\system32\RPCRT4.dll
ModLoad: 6e3e0000 6e45b000   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\mscoreei.dll
ModLoad: 75dc0000 75e17000   C:\Windows\system32\SHLWAPI.dll
ModLoad: 77590000 775de000   C:\Windows\system32\GDI32.dll
ModLoad: 75cf0000 75db9000   C:\Windows\system32\USER32.dll
ModLoad: 75f60000 75f6a000   C:\Windows\system32\LPK.dll
ModLoad: 75800000 7589d000   C:\Windows\system32\USP10.dll
ModLoad: 75f70000 75f8f000   C:\Windows\system32\IMM32.DLL
ModLoad: 75e80000 75f4c000   C:\Windows\system32\MSCTF.dll
ModLoad: 69670000 69d0b000   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
ModLoad: 6b1f0000 6b2c3000   C:\Windows\system32\MSVCR110_CLR0400.dll
(470.fb8): Unknown exception - code 04242420 (first chance)
ModLoad: 68640000 6966e000   C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32    \mscorlib\ce5f61c5754789df97be8dc991c47d07\mscorlib.ni.dll
ModLoad: 75f90000 760ec000   C:\Windows\system32\ole32.dll
ModLoad: 75350000 7535c000   C:\Windows\system32\CRYPTBASE.dll
ModLoad: 74200000 74240000   C:\Windows\system32\uxtheme.dll
ModLoad: 711d0000 71228000   C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\ink\tiptsf.dll
ModLoad: 75c10000 75c9f000   C:\Windows\system32\OLEAUT32.dll
ModLoad: 74910000 74919000   C:\Windows\system32\version.dll
ModLoad: 6c810000 6c88d000   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clrjit.dll
ModLoad: 6bb80000 6bbd2000   DCLib.dll
ModLoad: 003f0000 00442000   DCLib.dll
ModLoad: 74e70000 74e86000   C:\Windows\system32\CRYPTSP.dll
ModLoad: 74c10000 74c4b000   C:\Windows\system32\rsaenh.dll
ModLoad: 753f0000 753fe000   C:\Windows\system32\RpcRtRemote.dll
ModLoad: 590b0000 59a4a000   C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System\ff26cc03e6d57d8abd13b990332e67c6\System.ni.dll
ModLoad: 6ba90000 6bb80000   C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Configuration\bbc48ec4245e502ae19b0601d3799c9e\System.Configuration.ni.dll
ModLoad: 6a210000 6a3a4000   C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Drawing\5cd2aee5e7c07227c694d89219688ab3\System.Drawing.ni.dll
ModLoad: 566f0000 5733f000   C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Windows.Forms\f4f6ee0df2aa4189bf36e6335cb92761\System.Windows.Forms.ni.dll
ModLoad: 6cc50000 6cc62000   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\nlssorting.dll
ModLoad: 67ee0000 68631000   C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Xml\bada32953bb6b16a53d653eae23d78dc\System.Xml.ni.dll
(470.fb8): C++ EH exception - code e06d7363 (first chance)
(470.fb8): C++ EH exception - code e06d7363 (first chance)
(470.fb8): C++ EH exception - code e06d7363 (first chance)
(470.fb8): CLR exception - code e0434352 (first chance)
(470.fb8): C++ EH exception - code e06d7363 (first chance)
(470.fb8): CLR exception - code e0434352 (first chance)
(470.fb8): CLR exception - code e0434352 (first chance)
ModLoad: 6a130000 6a204000   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\diasymreader.dll
(470.fb8): CLR exception - code e0434352 (!!! second chance !!!)
eax=0015e804 ebx=00000005 ecx=00000005 edx=00000000 esi=0015e8c4 edi=00000001
eip=756c812f esp=0015e804 ebp=0015e854 iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz ac po nc
cs=001b  ss=0023  ds=0023  es=0023  fs=003b  gs=0000             efl=00000212
KERNELBASE!RaiseException+0x58:
756c812f c9              leave
```

I've entered .loadby sos clr and !pe and that gives the following

```
c0000005 Exception in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\sos.pe debugger extension.
  PC: 6b3d42c3  VA: 00000000  R/W: 0  Parameter: 0001007f
```

Googling that I can only find http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6a0af34b-ce48-4dcb-8b87-ed80f9477a86/windbg-clrjitdll-exception?forum=architecturegeneral which is unanswered. Googling to get further I found "!dumpheap -type Exception" which gives

```
688391fc        1           12 System.Text.DecoderExceptionFallback
688391b8        1           12 System.Text.EncoderExceptionFallback
68842570        1           84 System.ExecutionEngineException
6884252c        1           84 System.StackOverflowException
688424e8        1           84 System.OutOfMemoryException
68842394        1           84 System.Exception
6883c644        1           96 System.IO.FileNotFoundException
688425b4        2          168 System.Threading.ThreadAbortException
6884b940        2          176 System.TypeInitializationException
```

Which brings me back to the TypeInitializationException, I read somewhere else already that loading ExecutionEngineException, StackOverflowException and OutOfMemoryException always happens so they can be thrown when they occur instead of the need to create them at that point.

Remote debugging and checking all Thrown exceptions finally gives this line of information:

```
 The assembly with display name 'DCLib' failed to load in the 'Load' binding context of the AppDomain with ID 1. The cause of the failure was: System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'DCLib, Version=1.0.0.3, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies.
```

I found out the BadImageFormatException had to do with 64 bit software being called on a 32 bit system so I commentend out code using Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection and such that I needed for a component to work on my development machine. Then the program actually remotely starts when inside the VS debugger but only after clicking continue a couple of times, and as the program still doesn't start on the test machine itself at least one of the messages I click away needs to be resolved as well  ...

The second problem was also a TypeInitializationException, it searched for some SQL Server 2012 class or dll while the SQL Server installed on the test machine was SQL Server 2008. After I installed SQL Server 2012 everything worked. So handy that a .Net application not just tells in a log files or something what it searches for and cannot find, but rather just crashes and tells nothing and it's needed to do a remote debug session to find out.

Comment: At the time of the crash, create a dump with `.dump /ma x:\mycrash.dmp` so that you have enough time to analyze it later, without the risk of terminating the process. Especially if the problem does not reproduce well. From the given information, it's hard to tell the exact cause. You need a `.loadby sos clr` and `!pe` for the details.

Comment: "What's the actual problem?" is indeed too broad. For a question like "How to continue from this point?" I'd only see the two above mentioned commands as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

**What it means:**

Exception code `e0434352` could be anything. It just denotes a CLR exception of which there are many, many types. To get more information, you would have to use something like [`!PrintException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb190764%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) from `SOS.dll`

---

**Some advice:**

It seems like you are new to WinDbg. If you are more familiar with the Visual Studio debugger, you may have better luck installing the [Remote Debugging Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bt727f1t%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on your test machine and debugging from a full-blown instance of VS2012 on your development machine. That is not to say you wouldn't benefit from learning to use WinDbg. :)

---

**Psychic Debugging:**

What fun would it be if I didn't take a guess at the actual problem with almost no evidence whatsoever?

Given that your code works on a dev machine and not on a test machine, and the fact that the exception is thrown right after `diasymreader.dll` is loaded, I'm going to guess that some code is attempting to resolve a symbol name, perhaps using `System.Diagnostics.SymbolStore` and it is not finding the pdb file as it would on your dev machine.

Again, that is just a wild guess. You should tackle the problem using the `SOS` WinDbg extension or the Visual Studio debugger before you trust my psychic debugging abilities -- but be sure to let me know if I was right.

Comment: You weren't right, but at least part of your reply was helpful. Even though the next time I run into something alike I will immediately turn to remote debugging as that does give clear information about what's wrong where Windbg doesn't (or it's too complicated, hidden in some layer of darkness that can only be reached by pressing the correct followup of not always logical commands ...)